# hamburger Menu not responding when clicking

Tags: android, android-layout

hello i have a problem my hamburger icon not showing the drawer when clicking on it 
i don't know why i have the same code on other activities and it's working just fine

this is my layout

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >



<RelativeLyout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />
```

and this is whatapp_bar layout contains

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">

    <com.vpapps.utils.StatusBarView
        android:id="@+id/statusBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and this is my java code MainActivity.java

```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_whatsap_status_saver);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });
        toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.nav);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Android provides default hamburger icon for this operation.

Simply remove below two lines of code

```
toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.nav);
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

Comment: this line is just for changing the icon and after removing them still same problem